# tfs isubscriber job extension run event no longer fires

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I have currently run to a current problem that my tfs server plugin will no longer run a job when i call the method jobService.QueueOneTimeJob. No exceptions are thrown by for some reason I get the following warning:

"Extension name TFS.Plugin.TFSCreateProcesJobExtension is used by type TFS.Plugin.TFSCreateProcesJobExtension and TFS.Plugin.TFSCreateProcesJobExtension"

which makes me wonder what the hell is going on . I also noticed there is a tfsshellexet error on my event log too.

This had run before, and fired the 'run' event too.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 2):

I have managed to fix this issue now, it was the name of the manifest of the plugin had changed which stopped the jobextension run method not executing correctly.After placing enabling the tracing and  logging functionality.